# If $A$ is convex and $x \in \overline{A}$, is $A \cup \{x\}$ also convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space and $A \subseteq X$ a convex subset.

Let $x \in \overline{A}$ be a point contained in the closure of $A$. Must the set $A \cup \{x\}$ also be convex?

I'm pretty much confident the answer has to be yes, but haven't been able to prove it. I considered examples such as the open ball plus one point on its boundary, open convex polygons in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with one vertex added and such.

I'm aware of the fact that $\overline{A}$ is a convex set. Also, interestingly, if we have two points $x, y \in \overline{A}$ then $A \cup \{x, y\}$ is not convex in general:

Consider $A = \langle 0, 1 \rangle \times \langle 0, 1\rangle$ as a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $A \cup \{(0,1), (1,1)\}$ is not convex as the the segment between $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$ is not contained in $A \cup \{(0,1), (1,1)\}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already know that $A\cup\{x,y\}$ may fail to be convex. Now if you replace $A$ with $A\cup \{y\}$ you have your counterexample.
Spelled out, let $A=\langle 0,1\rangle \times \langle 0,1\rangle \cup\{(1,1)\}$ and $x=(0,1)$.

Comment: Yes, I have considered that, but I wasn't entirely sure that $\langle 0, 1 \rangle \times \langle 0, 1 \rangle \cup \{(1,1)\}$ is convex. How would you prove it?

Comment: @mechanodroid It doesn't matter whether $A\cup\{y\}$ is convex or not! If not then $A$ plus $y$ is the counterexample you want. If yes then $A\cup \{y\}$ plus $x$ is the counterexample you want.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Nice! This is similar to the famous proof that an irrational power of an irrational number can be rational, with $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You already essentially have the answer. You already noticed that $A\cup\{x,y\}$ need not be convex. If $A\cup\{x\}$ is not convex, this gives your counterexample. If $A\cup\{x\}$ is convex, then adding $y$ breaks this, giving your counter-example.